# Antiderivative and elementary functions

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Is there a theorem or method to prove that we can't express the antiderivative of some functions with elementary functions ? For example Gamma or Zeta or $\dfrac{\sin x}{x!}$? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra)).

The use of such a result in order to prove the non-existence of an elementary primitive for some functions (among them, the famous $e^{-x^2}$) is explained in [these notes](http://wstein.org/edu/winter06/20b/Conrad.pdf) by Brian Conrad.